# How to extract the hover box information in watir and print it to a STDOUT

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

I have to print the hover box information content on to stdout  and i tried it in the below fashion it didn't work for me .

```
data = $browser.div(:class => "homeSectionLabel textWidget",:text => /Pool A/ ).hover

print "Data  #{data} \n"
```

And the other problem that i have other widget called Pool B with same class name . How to access that hover information

```
<div class="widgetContainer poolContainer">
<div class="healthBadge healthUnknown" style="top: -5px; left: -5px;"></div>
<div class="homeSectionLabel textWidget">Pool‌·A</div>
<div class="perfDisplay homePoolPerf">
</div>
<div class="homePoolVolText textWidget">9‌·Volumes,‌·0‌·Snapshots</div>
<div class="spaceMeterContainer poolMeter" style="width: 265px; height: 20px;">
</div>
<table class="tableWidget homeTiers" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
</table>
</div>
```

Anyhelp is really  appreciated .

Thanks!
Aditya

Comment: Please provide the HTML or a link to the page that you are testing so we can help you.

Comment: Aditya, you need to write these types of questions like you were writing a defect for a developer. If people cannot reproduce the issue, they have a hard time figuring out the solution that would work for you. People rarely want to make an effort if you cannot provide basic information like html, your code (which you provided), and what didn't work (was there an error message?).

Comment: Sigh..  two days gone by, he was last seen 7 hours ago, and still no trace of sample html.. makes you wonder how badly an answer is needed?

Comment: I have added my HTML sample snippet guys ......!!!!  yeah i know i was late in uploading that HTML code

Comment: So what text are you expecting to get from the hover?  Is it the content of one of the divs shown above?

Comment: yes the content from the divs on to a variable so that i can print them on to a file for on to a STDOUT

Comment: Let me make a slightly more specific version of the question from @anonygoose. WHICH div above holds the text that you are trying to capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much of an answer at the moment, but what I have to say won't fit in a comment

The 'content' as in the text within a div is normally accessed with the .text method

'tooltip' text can be done in a number of ways, it could be via alt attributes, it could be via javascript triggered via an 'onmouseover' event, or it could be CSS driven usually via the :hover psuedoclass.

if a div is merely changing it's display property or location so that it becomes visible to the user, then all you need to do is figure out how to locate that div, and get the .text from it

mydata = browser.div(:how => 'what').text

If the content of the div (or some other container) is changing as a result of the mouseover/hover, then you need to simulate the action, wait a brief bit to allow client side code to run, and THEN get the .text from the container that was changed.

---

Without seeing a page that has the code working on it, it is hard to tell which is the case, although given that I see nothing like 'onmouseover' in the code you supplied, my first bet would be on this being CSS driven.

The code you have above is returning the result of the div object executing the .hover method, and that is going to be nil as far as I know since that method causes something to happen, but does NOT return a value.

Is the 'Pool A' the text you are trying to capture, or is it what you mouse_over to cause the other text to become visible to the user?  If it is what you mouseover, then have you searched the HTML to see if you can find the text that appears in some other div?

If you just need to get the text from every div of a given class, then try something like this

```
browser.divs(:class => "homeSectionLabel textWidget").each do |div|
  puts div.text
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most recent comment, this will gather the class names from all of the divs on the page and print it to the console.

```
$browser.divs.each do |div|
puts div.class
end
```

Replace "puts div.class" with a file directive if you want it in a file.  Any output here is simple Ruby.